# Qt Segmentation Fault strtod

Tags: c++, linux, qt, segmentation-fault

Whenever I try to parse a number (i.e. float, double, etc.) from a C string (char *), I get a segmentation fault and its very consistent.

On to the actual code:

```
//aLocation is a C++ object with two variables double Latitude & double Longitude. 
char** tokens; //Gets used in a string split function.
char* pEnd;
aLocation.setLatitude(strtod(tokens[0],&pEnd));  //tokens[0] = "26.379165"
aLocation.setLongitude(strtod(tokens[1],&pEnd)); //tokens[1] = "-80.101639"
```

It should be mentioned that I have tried alternative functions and data types (i.e. atoi, atof, strtol, strtof, & strtol).

I have checked the string split function and it works as expected. I can print the token values fine using "qDebug("Location: %s,%s",tokens[0],tokens[1](http://pcengines.ch/alix3d3.htm));". The two strtod() function calls above both seg fault (together or separately). When I remove the above two lines of code from my application, I get no seq faults at all.

---

The run environment is a custom Linux image I made using Buildroot and an older Linux Kernel (3.4.39). The application is written in C++ using the Qt 4.8.4 SDK. The device I am running the application on is the [alix3d](http://pcengines.ch/alix3d3.htm) motherboard, with some custom IC additions (over USB). I am also using the ld-uClibc.so.0 library.

**Location.h:**

```
#ifndef LOCATION_H
#define LOCATION_H

class Location
{
public:
    explicit Location();
    void setLatitude(double aLat);
    double getLatitude();
    void setLongitude(double aLong);
    double getLongitude();


private:
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

};

#endif // LOCATION_H
```

**Location.cpp:**

```
#include "location.h"

Location::Location()
{
}

void Location::setLatitude(double aLat){latitude=aLat;}

double Location::getLatitude(){return latitude;}

void Location::setLongitude(double aLong){longitude = aLong;}

double Location::getLongitude(){return longitude;}
```

**UPDATE**

```
Case 1: this->aLocation.setLatitude(1); ------> works (No additional code above or below)

Case 2:double aLat = (double)strtod(tokens[0], &pEnd); ---> works (No additional code below this)

Case 3: Below Code Seg faults 
double aLat = (double)strtod(tokens[0], &pEnd);
this->rsuLocation.setLatitude(aLat);
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? With that little (and incomplete) code it's impossible to actually say anything. For example, if you do the `strtod` calls separately and they work, then you know the error is not in those calls, but somewhere else. That way you can narrow down the problematic code for the creation of a MCVE. And you *have* tried to run in a debugger, to pinpoint the location of the crash?

Comment: The prime suspect would be the "string split function".

Comment: String split function works like a charm; I've been using it for some time now. I also validated my outputs by printing them out. Added more info above.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you skip the `strtod` functions, and rather just hard-set the `aLocation.setLatitude` and `aLocation.setLongitude` calls to constant values (i.e. the *only* thing trimmed out is the `strtod` calls) ? The very first thing I would have done is isolate those `strtod` calls to their own lines, setting local temps before passing those temps to your `aLocation` members. Shame this isn't under a *debugger*.

Comment: Regarding your edit, just because you can print a string and it *looks* okay, doesn't mean it actually is okay or correct, or that the pointer is correct. Also, the crash happens even if you do e.g. `double value = strtod(tokens[0], &pEnd); aLocation.setLatitude(value);`? Does the crash happens in `strtod`? Then the error is your string or your variable `tokens` (possible pointer problem). If the crash happens in `setLatitude` then you continue by looking there.

Comment: Lastly, this is why a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is so important. All we are doing now is ***guessing***. With a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we could actually see all the relevant code, and hopefully even try it ourselves, and we wouldn't have to guess and could give you a straight answer much quicker. Also, while creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there is a chance you could figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: It should be mentioned that based on the nature of the equipment I am working on there is no real way of using standard debugging tools like breakpoints or stepping through the code. The only real way to debug in this custom environment is to use print statements and debugfs (for the kernel side of stuff).

Comment: Sorry if I've missed something here but... I presume you're allocating the memory associated with `tokens` correctly -- presumably in the string split function or similar?

Comment: Did a "make clean" and the Location class is operating fine and the hardcoded values go through no problem. The parsing function appears to make it seg fault.

Comment: Yes, allocation is happening. G.M.

Comment: Incidentally, be very careful with `strtod` and Qt; given that Qt on Linux calls `setlocale("", LC_ALL)` in the `QApplication` constructor on Linux, `strtod` gets broken in locales where the decimal separator is comma. Make sure to revert back to the C locale if you plan to use `strtod` to parse machine-generated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a very Noobish move and forgot to call the constructor for the parent object.

In addition, I changed the include statements (i.e. #include ) too the QtCore library directory (i.e. #include ).